# Is it possible Nlog not to write the same message

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I want to see something like that:

error1
50 times: error2
error3
10 times: error2

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can try and play with `WhenRepeated`-filter:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WhenRepeated-Filter

```xml
  <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="randomTarget">
    <filters>
      <whenRepeated layout="${message}" timeoutSeconds="30" action="Ignore" />
    </filters>
  </logger>
```

But it is usually better just not to write the same message multiple times.

Comment: Thank you @RolfKristensen! There are some parameters like FilterCountPropertyName, which can help me.